# Lua installation error with makefile mingw

Tags: lua, mingw

```
PS C:\lua-5.1.5> make mingw
cd src && C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/make/tools/install/bin/make.exe mingw
make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/lua-5.1.5/src'
C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/make/tools/install/bin/make.exe "LUA_A=lua51.dll" "LUA_T=lua.exe" \
"AR=gcc -shared -o" "RANLIB=strip --strip-unneeded" \
"MYCFLAGS=-DLUA_BUILD_AS_DLL" "MYLIBS=" "MYLDFLAGS=-s" lua.exe
make[2]: Entering directory 'C:/lua-5.1.5/src'
gcc -shared -o lua51.dll lapi.o lcode.o ldebug.o ldo.o ldump.o lfunc.o lgc.o llex.o lmem.o lobject.o lopcodes.o lparser.o lstate.o lstring.o ltable.o ltm.o lundump.o lvm.o lzio.o lauxlib.o lbaselib.o ldblib.o liolib.o lmathlib.o loslib.o ltablib.o lstrlib.o loadlib.o linit.o     # DLL needs all object files
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find #: No such file or directory
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find DLL: No such file or directory
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find needs: No such file or directory
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find all: No such file or directory
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find object: No such file or directory
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find files: No such file or directory
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Makefile:51: lua51.dll] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/lua-5.1.5/src'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:107: mingw] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/lua-5.1.5/src'
make: *** [Makefile:56: mingw] Error 2
```

I am trying to compile lua-5.1.5 with makefile, i'm getting all these errors cannot find XXX

could not figure out where went wrong. anybody able to help? thankyou

Comment: See https://www.lua.org/bugs.html#5.1.5-1

Comment: It's Lua, not LUA. See https://www.lua.org/about.html ("What's in a name?" section) tl;dr it's commonly mistook for an acronym, but it's actually the Portuguese word for 'moon'.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the [Lua bugs page](https://www.lua.org/bugs.html#5.1.5-1), just edit `src/Makefile` to remove `# DLL needs all object files`.